# How to handle duplicate items in a combobox

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am having trouble with a telerik combobox in silverlight

I have defined it like this,

```
<telerik:RadComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Organisation, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Organisations}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

And the SelectedItem property bound to looks like this,

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The organisation is required.")]
public OrganisationEntity Organisation
{
    get
    {
        return utilityOwnerOrganisation;
    }
    set
    {
        utilityOwnerOrganisation = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(this, x => x.UtilityOwnerOrganisation);
    }
}
```

The OrganisationEntity is like this,

```
public class OrganisationEntity 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem arises if the list Organisations have two organisations in it defined like this,

```
new OrganisationEntity() { Name = "Wellington City Council", OrganisationId = 34 }
new OrganisationEntity() { Name = "Wellington City Council", OrganisationId = 31 }
```

If I have two items with the same Name in the list and set the Organisation property (from the viewmodel) to be the item with OrganisationId = 31 the setter is called from the binding engine and the other item gets selected.

The reason is because of DisplayMemberPath being set to Name. It is treating the Name as being a key and assuming that it is unique in the combobox, but it isn't.

If I take out the DisplayMemberPath it works, but the combobox then displays the wrong thing.

If I take out the DisplayMemberPath and define a ToString method to return the Name property in the OrganisationEntity the same thing occurs.

Comment: How are you're users going do differentiate between which organizational entity they are selecting? This sounds more like a design problem than a wpf problem.

Comment: Sure, agreed. It is a design problem because of the data in our database has duplicates. We will fix that long term. The reason we need to have two items the same in the list is because other tables in our database link to these organisation entities. The popup that this combo is on has those other records too and it's that link that needs to make sure the correct one is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the DisplayMemberPath and use a DataTemplate to show what you want instead:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Organisations}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I have explored that option. That particular template ItemTemplate just seems to control what is shown in the listbox part of the combobox, and not the main textbox. Is there another template that controls the main textbox - I couldn't find that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying, maybe RadComboBox do not work like the default sl 4 combobox? Because what is displayed on the main textbox is exactly the datatemplate...

Comment: If IsEditable is set to true on the combobox then the text in the 'TextBox' is not correct. Otherwise you are right, the template above works.

Comment: So my 'work around' solution for the moment is to apply the template above, and remove the option 'IsEditable = true'. The worst consequence of that is the user cannot type the organisation and use auto complete. That is less important than stopping the weirdness.